# Use Videos from Any Provider with a Custom Visualforce Page in External Domain

Tags: community, richtextarea

We have a community in Salesforce.

We publish KB articles.

We want to embed private videos (the ones we'd host in Salesforce itself, e.g. using `servlet.shepherd`).

Using this article:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_admin_tricks_examples_videos.htm&type=0 (`Use Videos from Any Provider with a Custom Visualforce Page`) we managed to get Attachments to the article work when customer goes to the community via `https://mydomain.force.com/community`. However, we also have an external URL to the community in the format `https://community.mydomain.com`

As per this article (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_using_html_editor_videos.htm&type=5) `Add Videos Using the HTML Editor` the HTML editor for the KB article simply removes the `iframe` tags unless they contain a Fully Qualified URL (so not relative) and that qualified URL HAS to be `.force.com`.

We made our VF page available to guest users, allowed iframing from any source, and added both internal and public URL as trusted sites everywhere, but then even though browser does load the iframe, salesforce drops the response instead of returning VF page content because they officially don't support iframing.

Is there a way to have a video player (e.g. using the HTML5 `video` tag) of attachments hosted in Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, turns out that the settings that you need to modify are `Security -> Session Settings -> Trusted Domains for Inline Frames`

Once that is added, the iframe with visualforce page loads.

Further to that, with the modern browsers you will have no access to cookies so the videos you are hosting have to be accessible to the Guest Profile of your Community.